# How to pass vmodel property to child component in nuxjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I can't seem to pass dynamically modified properties from layouts into the `<Nuxt />` component.

This is my `~/layouts/default.vue`

```
<template>
<div>
    <input v-model="myprop" />
    <span>{{myprop}}</span>
    <Nuxt />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  provide: function () {
    return {myprop: this.myprop};
  },

  data: () => ({
    myprop: 'hello galaxy',
  }),
}
</script>
```

This is my `~/pages/index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>My Prop is: {{myprop}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["myprop"]
}
</script>
```

On the web page I see `hello galaxy` printed 3 times, once in the input, once in a span, and once in the Nuxt component.  But when I edit the input field, only the span is updated.  The Nuxt component does not capture the changes in `myprop`.  The Nuxt component continues to show only `hello galaxy` while put the input and span shows changes as I type on my keyboard

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provide/inject is useful for simple situation, but if you've some reactive stuff the vuex store is more convenient :

in `store/index.js`

add a state called `search` and its mutations and actions :

```js
export const state=()=>({
  search:''
})

export const mutations ={
  SET_SEARCH(state,payload){
      state.search=payload
  }
}

export const actions ={
   setSearch(context,payload){
        context.commit('SET_SEARCH',payload)   ​
  }
}
```

in `layout/default.vue` add computed property with setter/getter bound to the store:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <input v-model="search" />
    <span>{{search}}</span>
    <Nuxt />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  computed:{
      search:{
        get(){
          return this.$store.state.search
        },
        set(val){
          this.$store.dispatch('setSearch',val)
        }
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

in `pages/index.vue` :

```html
<template>
  <div>My search is: {{search}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed:{
   search(){
      return this.$store.state.search
    }
   }
}
</script>
```